# how to use a controller from another module in Angular-ui-Bootstrap's modal?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a dialog I want to use in two different places, so I've built a template and a controller `trackCtrl` for a modal to use. That controller is defined on the `settingsApp` module which is not the one launching the modal, so I would like to do something like this:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
     templateUrl: 'templates/track.html',
     controller: 'settingsApp.trackCtrl'
});
```

but it fails of course.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

thanks!

Comment: You simply use the name of the controller, whatever its module is. At runtime, all the components are in the same namespace, whatever the module is.

Comment: I've got the following error:
"Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'trackCtrl' is not a function, got undefined"

Comment: Then the controller is not named 'trackCtrl', or it's not defined at all, or its module is not loaded. Hard to help without seeing the code.

Comment: The problem was that the js containing the controller's registration was not called. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the js file defining the controller was never run. 
(The controller should be referred to simply by its name.)

Answer (score 1):

Just add a dependency to your other module and then just simply use that controller name.

```
angular('app', ['settingsApp']);

var modalInstance = $modal.open({
     templateUrl: 'templates/track.html',
     controller: 'trackCtrl'
});
```

Comment: thanks, I guess in most cases it would work, but it doesn't work in my project.
I've paused on debug right before `$modal.open` command and `angular.module("settingsApp")` exists and reachable.
any other suggestions?